# TypeError: a is undefined in jsSHA

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA) JavaScript library to hash the passwords.

It's working fine when I just log in, but when I want to register a new user I'm getting the following error in console:

```
TypeError: a is undefined   jquery.min.js:8:5302
m/c()                       jquery.min.js:8 // empty line after jsSHA
b/this.update()             jquery.min.js:8
<anonymous>                 jquery.min.js:11 // empty line after the script
n.event.dispatch()          jquery.min.js:4 // jquery third line
n.event.add/r.handle()      jquery.min.js:4
```

I've minified the code and included it inside the jquery file, after the jquery code (it was giving me an error if I put it before, because of `'use strict'`).

The hash script is very basic, I just followed the instructions of the [README](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA#hashing) file:

```
$(function () {

    var a       = $('form#login'),
        b       = $('form#register'),
        c       = $('form#change_pwd'),
        shaObj  = new jsSHA('SHA-512', 'TEXT');

    a.on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var p = $('#password');

        shaObj.update(p.val());

        var p_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");

        p.val(p_hash);

        this.submit()

    });

    b.on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var p = $('#reg_pwd'),
            q = $('#confirm_pwd');

        shaObj.update(p.val());
        var p_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
        p.val(p_hash);

        shaObj.update(q.val());
        var q_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
        q.val(q_hash);

        this.submit()

    });

    c.on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var p = $('#current_pwd'),
            q = $('#new_pwd'),
            r = $('#confirm_newpwd');

        shaObj.update(p.val());
        var p_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
        p.val(p_hash);

        shaObj.update(q.val());
        var q_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
        q.val(q_hash);

        shaObj.update(r.val());
        var r_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
        r.val(r_hash);

        this.submit()

    })

});
```

The script is minified and included after the jsSHA code. The only difference are the variable names.

What is wrong with the script? It was happening too with this other [version](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html).

---

***SOLUTION***

The password fields don't have any id, so that's why it's giving the error. Sorry.

Comment: The most common question of javascript here in stackoverflow. If `form#login` doesn't exists in DOM when you try to attach the event, clearly will be undefined.

Comment: Not related with jsSHA plugin. It's a dom ready problem. Try to execute in a `window.onload` event, and probably you'll see the error disappear.

Comment: No, the error doesn't come from the script, it's from jsSHA code.

Comment: No, you are wrong. Comes from jQuery code, when jQuery try to add an event listener to an inexistent DOM element. In your case, when you register a new user, the login form doesn't exists, curiously the `a` element that the error said. Read carefully errors and what we tell you.

Comment: How do you try to attach an event to an unexistent element?

Comment: I can be wrong, but the console links the error to the jsSHA code, not my script.

Comment: I was using this code in native javascript and I've never had this problem, I switched to jquery and I'm getting it. I guess I can use a condition (`window.location.pathname`) to know the page i'm in and execute only the needed one.

Comment: If the element doesn't exists, you'll obtain the same result in jQuery and in vanilla javascript. Trust in me, your problem is that. And where do you see the error in the jsSHA library? Your console doesn't throw nothing related.

Comment: Yes sorry, in vanilla javascript I was using a `window.onload` (now that I remember) but inside the event I was doing the same, attach `onsubmit()` to the three forms (even when only one of them will be executed) and it was working. I still have the code in old backups. About the error, in the console I see `TypeError: a is undefined` and when I click the `jquery.min.js:8:5302` link I can see the jsSHA line selected, not my script's line.

Comment: `a is undefined` reffers to `a` variable. Your code breaks here: `a.on('submit', function (e) {` for sure. `a` is undefined and doesn't exist `a.on()` obviously. Try to comment that block of code in the register page and you'll see how it works, or at least a different error will be thrown.

Comment: I've already checked, changing the variable name from `var a = $("form#login")` to `var z = $("form#login")` and `z.on('submit'...` I still see the same error. The problem is not my script.

Comment: In login page it's obvious that `a` exists, because it's `form#login`. Your trace doesn't show the jsSHA problem, but if you are right, please, make a working example. You can write it in stacksnippets or in external services like jsfiddle.net . Otherwise I can't help you much more. Sorry :(

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude A jQuery selector call *never* returns `undefined`, whether or not the element is found in the DOM.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just realized and deleted that. I can find the exact trace but I'd have to use the developer version. There must be a `var a` in the jsSHA library. The one that gives the error I mean.

Comment: There's no dev version but there are more lines: https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/blob/master/src/sha512.js Using this version I'm getting `TypeError: c is undefined jquery.min.js:17:137` That is the line 22 in github. Maybe the uglifier changed the names.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't said that the jQuery selector is returned undefined, I said that the `a.on()` line throws `a is undefined`, however maybe OP is right but we need a working example to reproduce the issue

Comment: Ok found the problem.